# UWP consuming WCF: net_http_client_execution_error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, uwp, httpwebrequest

I'm facing this little trouble. I'm developing an app for UWP that make an HttpRequest for search some information constantly.

When makes over 90 calls the line WebRequest.CreateHttp throws net_http_client_execution_error. (The connection with server was reset)

If I execute the request in some explorer it works correctly.

How can I solve this?

```
for(int i=0;i<999;i++){
    for(int x=0;x<50000;x++){
         HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(String.Format(serverIP + 
                                                             "/{0}/{1}",                                                                                      
                                                            Convert.ToString(i),                                                                       
                                                            Convert.ToString(x)));
         request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
         WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
         Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
         string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
         AddMessage(text);
         reader.Dispose();
         dataStream.Dispose();
         response.Dispose();
         request.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient)? This is the one that recommend to use in UWP.

Comment: Hi. Yes! I tried with same result.

Comment: Sending so much (999x50000) requests would always not be a good idea. I think the problem here is not in the client side. Using some other client, such as a console app to send such amount of requests would also have the same issue.